# Cannot find AwesomeNotifications().actionStream

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

I would like to add a button to my flutter notification. The button is shown but I can't catch the action.

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
        id: 888,
        channelKey: 'NetVideo',
        title: 'NetVideo',
        body: 'Server in ascolto'),
    actionButtons: <NotificationActionButton>[
      NotificationActionButton(key: 'yes', label: 'Yes'),
    ],
  );
```

AwesomeNotifications().actionStream still exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications#-how-to-show-local-notifications):

> All streams (createdStream, displayedStream, actionStream and dismissedStream) was replaced by global static methods. You must **replace** your old stream methods by **static and global methods**, in other words, they must be static **Future** and use async/await and you MUST use **@pragma("vm:entry-point")** to preserve dart addressing.

In other words you should create a notification listener

```
class NotificationController {

  /// Use this method to detect when a new notification or a schedule is created
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future <void> onNotificationCreatedMethod(ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    // Your code goes here
  }

  /// Use this method to detect every time that a new notification is displayed
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future <void> onNotificationDisplayedMethod(ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    // Your code goes here
  }

  /// Use this method to detect if the user dismissed a notification
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future <void> onDismissActionReceivedMethod(ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    // Your code goes here
  }

  /// Use this method to detect when the user taps on a notification or action button
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future <void> onActionReceivedMethod(ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    // Your code goes here

    // Navigate into pages, avoiding to open the notification details page over another details page already opened
    MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/notification-page',
            (route) => (route.settings.name != '/notification-page') || route.isFirst,
        arguments: receivedAction);
  }
}
```

And register it inside the library

```
AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
    onActionReceivedMethod: (ReceivedAction receivedAction){
        NotificationController.onActionReceivedMethod(context, receivedAction);
    },
    onNotificationCreatedMethod: (ReceivedNotification receivedNotification){
        NotificationController.onNotificationCreatedMethod(context, receivedNotification);
    },
    onNotificationDisplayedMethod: (ReceivedNotification receivedNotification){
        NotificationController.onNotificationDisplayedMethod(context, receivedNotification);
    },
    onDismissActionReceivedMethod: (ReceivedAction receivedAction){
        NotificationController.onDismissActionReceivedMethod(context, receivedAction);
    },
);
```

Comment: Hi, I have one query. onActionReceivedMethod works fine when an app is in the foreground but does not work when an app is in the background. How to handle this?